# VBA Variable as CommandButton#

Tags: vba, excel

I'm rewriting some code and had a thought, but can't seem to get my syntax right to execute it properly.  I want to use a for loop to populate an array of commandbuttons as well as control their visibility.  I just need help with my syntax to define which CommandButton number I'm working on in the loop.  For instance, CommandButton1, CommandButton2, etc.

```
Public Sub LoadLots(sName As String, streamLots() As String)
    Label1.Caption = sName
    For o = 1 To 9
        If streamLots(o) <> "" Then
            CommandButton& o &.Caption = streamLots(o)
            CommandButton& o & .Visable = True
        Else
            CommandButton& o & .Visable = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Activesheet.Shapes("CommandButton" & o).Caption` ... also `Visable` should be `Visible`

Comment: I should have added, these buttons are on a form.

Comment: same principle, but you got the answer below as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Userform.Controls collection to reference the commandbuttons by name.

```
Public Sub LoadLots(sName As String, streamLots() As String)
    Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton
    Label1.Caption = sName
    For o = 1 To 9
        Set btn = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & o)
        If streamLots(o) <> "" Then
            btn.Caption = streamLots(o)
            btn.Visible = True
        Else
           btn.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Thanks for the check.