# How to use variable inside a variable in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a chunk of code that is calling a function `insertIntoPlannerFile` to do some updating as below

```
 Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier 1 po", rowNumber, prForm.po1Edit)
 Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier 1 po date", rowNumber, prForm.po1DateEdit)
```

Here `prForm` is the form name and `po1Edit` is the name of a textbox in that form. I have some other textbox also in the form such as `po2Edit`, `po3Edit` etc.

Since the above chunk of code is re using, I tried to make this also as a function. So I type the code as below

```
Function insertModule(objectNumber As String)
      Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier " & objectNumber & " po", rowNumber, prForm.po & objectNumber & Edit)
      Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier " & objectNumber & " po date", rowNumber, prForm.po & objectNumber & DateEdit)
End Function
```

And called the function as below

```
Call insertModule("1")
Call insertModule("2")
```

But somehow it is not working. Does anyone know how to change it into a re usable function?

Comment: I guess you need to put `Edit` resp `DateEdit` into quotes (`"Edit"` resp. `"DateEdit"`)

Comment: This question has been asked so many times in the past. Please search stackoverflow

Comment: @FunThomas No, variable names cannot be variable they have to be hardcoded.

Comment: @PEH, sorry, you are right, didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556935/vba-variable-as-commandbutton) is one such link. There are many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the numeber in `prForm.po1Edit` being variable, the only way to do this is using `Controls`.

```
prForm.Controls("po" & NumberVariable & "Edit")
```

because variable names cannot be dynamic.

---

Note that your `Function` does not return any values, therefore it should be a procedure `Sub`:

```
Sub insertModule(objectNumber As String)
      Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier " & objectNumber & " po", rowNumber, prForm.Controls("po" & objectNumber & "Edit"))
      Call insertIntoPlannerFile("supplier " & objectNumber & " po date", rowNumber, prForm.Controls("po" & objectNumber & "DateEdit"))
End Sub
```